# Reorder JavaScript numbered list

Tags: javascript, numbered-list

Currently using this simple JS Code to create a numbered list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          
          let current_number = 10; 
          function insertNumber(){
            document.write(current_number)
            current_number--
          }
          
          
  </script>
```

Then using this code to display each number in order on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">insertNumber()</script>
```

My question is, how can I reorder this list? Right now, it begins from 10 and counts down to 1, but I'd like to start the list off with 1 and end with 10.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Google `Array`, `Array.sort`. [Do not use `document.write`](https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2016/09/avoid-using-document-write-scripts-injection/)

Comment: `let current_number = 1; ... current_number++;`

Comment: Well, think about it. You start from `10` and are going down. Why don't you start from `1` up?

Comment: For loop try it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP can amply find answers on the Internet

Comment: can starting with '0' and checking if the number has reached '10' be a solution.

Comment: Thank you all, your suggestions have worked! The script example posted below did the trick.

As you can tell, I'm quite new at this. I did search the internet before posting, but admittedly wasn't sure what to search for, so not surprised it didn't return my desired results.

Also, thanks for the tip against using document.write, will look for alternatives to this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
          
  let current_number = 0; 
  function insertNumber(){
    if(current_number<=10)
    document.write(current_number)
    current_number++
  }   
          
</script>
```